# Regex: too much is matched in the second group

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
^No\.?\s?(\d+(?:(?:,\s?\d+)+,?\s?&\s?\d+)??),?\s?(hello)$
```

The following input matches:
`No. 1, 3, & 5, hello` where 
the first group is `1, 3, & 5` and the second group is `hello`. This is good so far, but now I would like to match any characters in the second group instead of `hello` and keep the first group. I tried

```
 ^No\.?\s?(\d+(?:(?:,\s?\d+)+,?\s?&\s?\d+)??),?\s?(.*?)$
```

but then only `1` is put in the first group and the rest is put in the second group.

Comment: Replace `??` with `?`

Comment: If you are matching from that point until the end of the string, you could also use `(.*)` instead of `(.*?)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew your answer works, thank you.

Comment: @The fourth bird, your are right, thank you, too.